# How to use rails scope or where clause to query OR AND conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

so I'm trying to make queries that look like this

```
Car Model
has_many :colors
scope :for_cars, ->(color) { Car.join(:color).where(colors: { name: color}) }
```

for cars of `green` OR `blue` i can do this.

```
Car.for_cars(['green', 'blue'])
```

and I want to get cars that are `green` AND `blue`, how do i do that?

I'm using postgres.

Comment: which RDBMS ???

Answer (score 2):

Query in this way:-

```
scope :for_cars, ->(color) { Car.joins(:colors).where("colors.name" =>  color) }
```

**Or** `in this way much simpler:-`

```
scope :for_cars, ->(color) { Car.joins(:colors).where("colors.name":  color) }
```

**Or** `in this way also if this scope is in Car model:-`

```
scope :for_cars, ->(color) { joins(:colors).where("colors.name":  color) }
```

**Note:** -`Tested in Rails 4.2.9`

Check the [Rails guides on joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: i blieve this is Either Color, I want to query for Both Color

Comment: the parameter can contain either one colour as `green` or array of colours  as `['green', 'blue']` and will work for both.

Comment: however, im looking for a car with both color 'green' and 'blue', not OR blue

Answer (score 1):

```
Car.for_cars('green').merge(Car.for_cars('blue'))
```

This will generate a single query with two joins and return intersection. https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge

But this approach gets ineffective as the number of desired colors grows (too many joins).

You can also do something like this:

```
wanted_colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow']

Car.for_cars(wanted_colors).group("cars.id").having("COUNT(colors.id) = #{wanted_colors.size}")
```

This approuch might defer depending on RDBMS you use.

Comment: that is still "Green" or "Blue", a union operation. I am looking for intersection.

Comment: This will be intersection. Added link

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this, without a scope, would be to have methods on Car:

```
def color_names
  colors.map(&:name)
end

def has_all_color_names(has_color_names = [])
  (color_names & has_color_names).size == has_color_names.size
end

def self.has_all_color_names(has_color_names = [])
  includes(:colors).select { |car| car.has_all_color_names has_color_names }
end
```

... and then to ...

```
Car.has_all_color_names %w(Green Blue)
```